# Existence or impossibility of Gaussian factory

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, gaussian, estimation-theory

**Gaussian factory problem**: given an iid sequence $x_i \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$, $i=1,2,\dots$, with $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ both unknown, construct a realization $y \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $z_1 = x_1 - x_2$, and $z_2 = x_3 - x_4$, then $z_1, z_2 \sim \mathcal{N}(0,2\sigma^2)$.

Let $z = z_1 / z_2$.  By results about ratios of Normal variates $z \sim \textrm{Cauchy}()$, i.e. is a standard Cauchy random variable.

Let $u = \frac{1}{\pi} \textrm{arctan}(z) + \frac{1}{2}$, the CDF of the standard Cauchy.  Therefore $u \sim \textrm{U}([0,1])$.

Let $y = \sqrt{2} \,\textrm{erf}^{-1}(2u - 1)$, using the quantile function of the standard Normal.

We have $y \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$.

Comment: You can even make do with only $x_1, x_2, x_3$, since $(x_1-x_2)/(x_1-x_3)$ already has a non-trivial distribution which does not depend on $\mu$ and $\sigma$.